# Does installing RStudio Desktop come with a pre-installed R?

Tags: r, rstudio

When you install **RStudio Desktop**, does it also come with a pre-installed **R**?

Answer (score 2):

From
[RStudio Desktop Professional Edition 2022.02.1+461.pro1](https://docs.rstudio.com/ide/desktop-pro/):

> **1.2 Prerequisites**
>
> **RStudio Desktop requires a previous installation of R** version 3.0.1 or
> higher. If you don’t already have R, download it from
> https://cran.rstudio.com/. A 64-bit version of R is required on macOS
> and Linux; RStudio Desktop Pro for Microsoft Windows supports both
> 32-bit and 64-bit R sessions.